# MongoDB - Return child property as alias name

Tags: mongodb

I have an collection like this:

```
[
  {
    "level1": {
      "level2": "value1"
    },
    "key": "value2"
  }
  ...
]
```

Now I wanna result after find likely:

```
[
  {
    "alias": "value1",
    "key": "value2"
  }
  ...
]
```

How can I do this in MongoDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use find with project:

```
db.collection.find({},
{
  alias: "$level1.level2",
  key: 1,
})
```

That allows you to decide with fields you get.